# run same sql queries for different tables at a time (bash script)

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I would like to add same columns into my multiple tables at a time using bash script from my Linux virtual machine terminal. I have three tables in my database:
**my_usa_table**,
**my_india_table**,
**my_germany_table**

**I want to add following columns for those three tables at a time.**
ALTER TABLE my_{$i}*table ADD COLUMN state VARCHAR(120) AFTER address;

ALTER TABLE my*{$i}*table ADD COLUMN zipcode VARCHAR(16) AFTER state;

ALTER TABLE my*{$i}_table ADD COLUMN language VARCHAR(100) AFTER zipcode;

*Here is my bash script:*

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a country=("usa","india","germany")
for i in "${country[@]}"
do
    mysql -uroot -p testdb -e "ALTER TABLE my_{$i}_table ADD COLUMN state VARCHAR(120) AFTER address";
    mysql -uroot -p testdb -e "ALTER TABLE my_{$i}_table ADD COLUMN zipcode VARCHAR(16) AFTER state";
    mysql -uroot -p testdb -e "ALTER TABLE my_{$i}_table ADD COLUMN language VARCHAR(100) AFTER zipcode";

done
```

But it is getting error. How may i fix it please ?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{usa}_company ADD COLUMN state VARCHAR(120) AFTER address' at line 1

Comment: you tagged both mysql and sqlserver. which database you are using?

Comment: Replace `";` by `;"`.

Comment: You say you want to do them "at a time".
The ";" at the end of each mysql doesn't do anything.  semi-colon is for separating commands on the same line, so that has no effect.
Why not enclose the 3 mysqls into an anonymous () block, run that in the background with & after it, and have all 3 countries running at once?
Assuming these tables are quite big, that'd save time.
Also I don't know mysql but I'd expect it to be able to add the 3 columns concurrently, from a single statement .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace `my_{$i}_table` wit this `my_$i_table`

Comment: or replace `my_{$i}_table` by `my_${i}_table`.